# Google authentication with Java apache http tokens

Tags: java, http, token, authentication

I'm trying to authenticate with Google using a simple Java program. I post to the correct URL with my credentials. I get a response with HTTP status code 200 but that doesn't contain any of the authentication tokens that I need to retrieve feeds for the user. Here's the code

```
private static String postData = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?Content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded&accountType=GOOGLE&Email=xxxxxxxx&Passwd=xxxxx";

public GoogleConnector(){
    HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost method=new HttpPost(postData);
    try{
        HttpResponse response=client.execute(method);
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e){ 
    }
```

Comment: Was that a typo when you were posting your code example or is there really two spaces between `Content-` and the rest of your URL?

Comment: ah sorry about that, its just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the first problem you have is that 'Content-Type' needs to be a header, not a request parameter. And secondly, POST parameters should be appended to the request body, not to the request URL. Your code should look something like this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost method = new HttpPost("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
method.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

List<BasicNameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(4);
postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accountType", "GOOGLE"));
postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", "xxxxxxx"));
postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passwd", "xxxxxx"));
postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("service", "cl"));

UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams);
method.setEntity(formEntity);

HttpResponse response=client.execute(method);
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Comment: It works but still, I don't get the SID, LSID and Auth cookies in the response. I do get a status 200 which means that it should be authenticated but I don't get the tokens

Comment: When I POST this request in REST Client I get the SID and LSID in the response body, not headers.

Comment: Great it works, thank you. But from what I read, SID and LSID should not be used and the Auth token should be used instead. Thing is, I can't find the Auth token in the response body. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Looks like you also need to specify the `service` parameter in order to get back an `Auth` token.

Comment: Yes that's right, perfect :)) Thank you very much. Just a quick note, for others who come and read this post the parameter is "Passwd" and not "Password" so you might wanna edit that just to avoid confusion.

Comment: No problem. Good catch on the password field, I've updated my answer to correct that and add the service parameter. Good luck with the rest of the program.